# Unable to parse string of json which is passed as an argument from other node program

Tags: javascript, node.js

*** Update :*** i had enclosed the changeSet in double quotes too inspite of that i still get the same error

**This is what am trying to achieve**

am calling script function which checks the newly modified files in my project and passes those as a String in the form of JSON to another node program as an argument

where i can use that Json to perform the tasks

however am unable to parse that string into JSON

so the JSON in question is this
**{"changeSet":[{"time":"2019-06-2810:22:57","fileName":"src/MainHandler.jsx"},{"time":"2019-06-2013:08:45","fileName":"resSet.json"}]}**

node findChanges changesJson

in the function where this is being passed as an argument

i tried all sorts of things

like parsing it through JSON.parse method

to trimming the argument and then parsing it ,no matter what i do , i keep getting syntax Error

i have also tried enclosing the changeSet attribute in double Quotes still i keep getting the same error

```
let cs = process.argv[2];

let b = JSON.parse(cs); //here I get the parsing error

console.log(b.changeSet);

//i have also tried stringifying it first and parsing it 
//trimming it --->stringifying it ---->parsing it
```

```
undefined:1
{changeSet
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: That's not valid [JSON](http://json.org). Properties have to enclosed in quotes, and `changeSet` isn't. Whoever creates the "JSON" is doing it wrong.

Comment: What is the error that you get after putting the `changeSet` in quotes. Please show that, and show the complete error.

Comment: And can you do a `console.log(cs)` and show us the output?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON in question is invalid, you need to add quotes around changeSet, e.g.

```
{
    "changeSet": [
        {
            "time": "2019-06-2810:22:57",
            "fileName": "src/MainHandler.jsx"
        },
        {
            "time": "2019-06-2013:08:45",
            "fileName": "resSet.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result =  {"changeSet":[{"time":"2019-06-2810:22:57","fileName":"src/MainHandler.jsx"},{"time":"2019-06-2013:08:45","fileName":"resSet.json"}]};

console.log(result.changeSet)
```

Problem is in your input. ChangeSet should be in the quotes.

You may try to give input as below format:

> {"changeSet":[{"time":"2019-06-2810:22:57","fileName":"src/MainHandler.jsx"},{"time":"2019-06-2013:08:45","fileName":"resSet.json"}]}

Before started working, always check on it [Onlint JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: Hi Shivani patel, 
thanks for responding
have tried that too 
in the description of the question you can see me saying that , i still get the same issue

Answer (score 1):

you miss quotes around your json-string.